# Is the USA Democratic?

Tags: democracy, parties, lobbying, proportional-representation, money-supply

I know this sounds weird since the USA is always regarded as a democracy or a republic which means people but when I study how elections are conducted and the actual system, it doesn't sound like a democracy...
So there's this thing called the Electoral College which basically is a set amount of votes for each state that a candidate must win, so fast forward and this creates a discrepancy between the popular vote and the Electoral College, SO a candidate can get more than 50 percent of all individual votes and still lose, so that means the winning candidate has support of <50% of all voters, even the Soviet Union required its leaders to have more than 50 percent of support of the people in one party elections. Another reason why one could doubt the US is a democracy is because its elections are extremely influenced by money, money makes the world spin and in elections it is vital, Money is used for advertising, lobbying, and big companies lobby political candidates to NOT work in their own interests and in the interests of the Corporate Sector. So take all this into account and it doesn't sound like a democracy does it? Also the USA is a 2-party system, which was not even supported by the founding fathers.

Comment: The United States is a "Representative Democracy" and a "Republic".  In U.S. Political Science the two phrases are often used interchangeably owing to the fact that the former term didn't exist, and their government model was the Roman Republic.   In general term a Republic is any nation where the head of State is not a Monarch.  It's important to note that the U.S. is not a Direct Democracy (each citizen votes on every legislative issue.).

Comment: Recommended reading: The articles of confederacy (from the founding fathers), to get a sense of what problem the framers were trying to address and why they believed that direct democracy was bad (hint: education). Also The Prince (from Machiavelli) to understand how the models of government were understood at the time (and such works were frequently read by people like the founders). Trying to view the design decisions anachronistically is what is causing what appears to be contradiction.